# i want install wine 2.0 stable (package standard) on a live usb lubuntu 16.10 .Is it compatible

Tags: lubuntu, wine

My station:lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.8.0-22-generic (buildd@lgw01-55) (gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) ) #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:14:42 UTC 2016

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo cat  /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=yakkety
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.10"

I'm not a Linux specialist.
If it is possible , what are the commands  and with what ppa

Comment: May I ask why you wish to install WINE on a volatile environment? It seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know, then here you go.

To add the software repository: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds`
To install: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install winehq-devel`
 Do keep in mind that **ANYTHING** you "install" on this live usb will be lost when you shutdown. If you are looking to use Ubuntu off of a usb then you need to install Ubuntu on the usb. (aka make it persistant)